# How do I connect to the network with an OCI instance?

Tags: oracle

I recently signed up for OCI Free Tier, but I can't seem to access the internet from within the instance. What should I do?

This problem occurred after the apt-get update command and although it finds the ubuntu mirror server ( archive.ubuntu.com:80 )
Doesn't rise above 0%
I also tried the ping command, but it says that even if I find the server address, it is 100% lost.

I'm a new developer and I'm not sure how to deal with this.

I opened the port 80,443 of the firewall and updated VNC and assigned a fixed address.
Same phenomenon repeated
I couldn't check the arp command because there is no net-tools package, but judging from the mirror server or ping command, the internet connection looks up the DNS server, but it doesn't seem to upload/download.

Comment: Did you create an Internet Gateway to communicate with the Internet? . Does your default route point to the IGW?

Comment: Yes I created VNC and completed opening 0.0.0.0/0 CIDR for HTTPS,HTTP port over secure subnet

Comment: Opened port 80,443 for both send and receive